# Using "docker image ls" as data source for Yii ActiveRecord

Tags: php, docker, activerecord, yii, orm

I'd like to construct a DockerImage model which data source is the command-line, like executing `docker image ls` to get a list of all images installed. Running

```
DockerImage->findAll()
```

would fetch `docker image ls` and construct a DockerImage object for each line read.

Any tips on how to achieve this? Maybe construct a custom Query class?

**Edit**:

Example output from `docker image ls`:

```
$ docker image ls
REPOSITORY               TAG                         IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
mysql                    latest                      8d99edb9fd40        12 days ago         445MB
httpd                    2.4                         74ad7f48867f        8 months ago        177MB
hello-world              latest                      725dcfab7d63        8 months ago        1.84kB
```

Each line should correspond to a Model object, and each column is an attribute on that object.

**Edit 2**: It might be enough to subclass the `Command` class, then set `$commandMap` in the database connection using a new driver type called `commandline`, *or* also subclass the connection into a `CommandlineConnection`.

Comment: Why do you want to use ActiveRecord for this? The whole point of ActiveRecord is that it is *active* - it can insert or update itself in database. How do you want to do this with `docker image ls` result?

Comment: @rob006 Fair point. I only need to read data, but I want to do it in a structured way, not just reading a bunch of arrays and loop on them. ActiveRecord can be used for read-only data, too, no?

Comment: Or is the Yii ORM only suitable for database storage?

Comment: AR can be used for read-only data, but it does not make much sense - you're using then like 10% of AR features. If you want structured data, you can use simple entity with defined properties and some tool which will parse `docker image ls` result to collection of these entities. Involving `ActiveRecord` or `Query` into this looks like big overcomplication for me.

Comment: @rob006 There's no go-to design pattern to convert data to CModel objects or sim in Yii?

Comment: `CModel` is relatively simple object, what kind of pattern do you expect?

Comment: @rob006 I was expecting an abstraction layer between data source and model object, in which I could insert my own command-line data source and still use the model system.